# Составление регулярки

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь написать регулярку под команду string.replaceAll
Исходный текст имеет такой вид:

```
dialog_from1_who1
dialog_who1_from1
dialog_from2_who2
dialog_who2_from2
dialog_from3_who3
dialog_who3_from3
```

Нужно спарсить во всем случаях who№ при условии что from№ всегда известен.
 [dialog_что сюда писать не знаю]

Comment: непонятно...надо заменить всё же (replace) или спарсить? Вроде это разные операции... Если заменить, то что на что... если спарсить, то что ожидается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String str = "dialog_from1_who1 dialog_who3_from3" 
+ "dialog_who1_from1"
+ "dialog_from2_who2"
+ "dialog_who2_from2"
+ "dialog_from3_who3"
+ "dialog_who3_from3";

String newString = str.replaceAll("\\w+from3", "mystring").replaceAll("\\w+from3\\w+", "mystring");
```

`\\w+from3` - соответствует dialog_who1_from3

`\\w+from3\\w+` - соответствует dialog_from3_who3

если слово `dialog` будет всегда. то нужно писать так

```
String newString = str.replaceAll("dialog_\\w+from3", "mystring").replaceAll("dialog_from3\\w+", "mystring");
```

Comment: illegal escape character ошибка . Ругается на слеши. Если  я удваиваю слеш, то регулярка не работает.

Comment: @НиколаКривошея исправил. надо было экранировать сдеши